# jquery append td

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to append a td after the end of an existing td. Below is the following code (I am doing it in jqgrid).

```
$("#list_toppager_center tr:first td:eq(7)").append("<td class='ui-paging-info'>Col/td>");
```

I see that column gets added, but it gets added below the column I am trying to append to instead of adding beside. Is the above solution the right way to do it?

Comment: What does the rest of the table look like?  How many other tds are there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like that should help hopefully:

```
$(function(){
    $("#list_toppager_center tr:first td:last").after("<td class='ui-paging-info'>Col</td>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `<` on the closing `</td>`.  I also think you want to select the row and append to that; you are adding a cell inside of a cell, which would make invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Tables have rows each with the same number of columns... You might add the append for each of the other rows (past row 1).

see: [jQuery add HTML table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075415/jquery-add-html-table-column)

```
$("#list_toppager_center tr:first").append("<td class='ui-paging-info'>New Col<td>");<br />
$("#list_toppager_center tr:gt(0)").append("<td> </td>");<br />
```