# How to append multiple table cells using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, append

```
jq('#table1') 
  .append(jq('<tr>') 
    .append(jq('<td>') 
      .append('data1' 
      ) 
    ) 
  );
```

I want to append more than one `<td>` to my current `<tr>`, each of these `<td>` has different format, so I can not just use a for loop to create bunch of `<td>`. The `( )` in this case is very tricky, anybody got an idea how this might work?

By ***each of these `<td>` has different format***, I mean that I need to add $ to some of the cells that representing money, etc.

Comment: What do you mean each has a different format?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you're trying to do if you want a good answer.

Comment: Hiya - this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075415/jquery-add-html-table-column , cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  jq('#table1') 
  .append(jq('<tr>') 
    .append(jq('<td>').append('data1')) 
    .append(jq('<td>').append('data1')) 
    .append(jq('<td>').append('data2')) 
    .append(jq('<td>').append('data3'))     
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
jq('#table1').append(
    jq('<tr>')
        .append(jq('<td>').append('data1')) 
        .append(jq('<td>').append('data2')) 
        .append(jq('<td>').append('data3')) 
);
```

EDIT: Corrected to append tds, not data in tds

Comment: In ur case, I would be adding data to the same <td> cell

Comment: My apologies, I misread your goal.  I corrected the above to reflect what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Create the markup first and append everything at last for best performance:

```
var tds = [
    '<td>...</td>',
    '<td>...</td>',
    '<td>...</td>'
];

$('#table').append('<tr>' + tds.join('') + '</tr>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jq("#table1").append("<tr></tr>");
```

then;

```
jq("#table1 tr:last").append("<td></td>");
jq("#table1 tr:last").append("<td></td>");
jq("#table1 tr:last").append("<td></td>");
jq("#table1 tr:last").append("<td></td>");
```

will append 4 td's to your last added tr.

Comment: and if you want data inside the td's, you'd just write "<td>"+data+"</td>" inside the brackets.