# How to delete a column by Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

How to delete a column using below code. I'm using jquery and joomla.

```
jQuery("a.coldelete").live("click", function(){
                    var Index = jQuery(this).closest("th").prevAll("th").length;
                    var CostIndex = Index *2 - 1;
                    var SaleIndex = Index *2; 
                    alert(Index+'-'+CostIndex+'-'+SaleIndex);

                    jQuery("#ratecardlist").find("th:eq("+Index+")").remove();

                    jQuery("#labelrow").find("td:eq("+CostIndex+")").remove();
                    jQuery("#labelrow").find("td:eq("+SaleIndex+")").remove();

                    jQuery("#ratecardlist").find("tr.ratedatarow").each(function(){
                          jQuery(this).find("td:eq("+CostIndex+")").remove();
                          jQuery(this).find("td:eq("+SaleIndex+")").remove();
                    });
              });
```

HTML structure is mentioned below which is to be manipulated by jquery.

```
<table id="cardlist" class="admintable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Show Time</th>
            <th colspan="2" style="text-align:left;">A Full <a href="#ratecardinfo" class="coldelete"><img src="com/assets/images/remove.png" /></a></th>
            <th colspan="2" style="text-align:left;">A Half <a href="#ratecardinfo" class="coldelete"><img src="com/assets/images/remove.png" /></a></th>
            <th colspan="2" style="text-align:left;">B Full <a href="#ratecardinfo" class="coldelete"><img src="com/assets/images/remove.png" /></a></th>
            <th colspan="2" style="text-align:left;">B Half <a href="#ratecardinfo" class="coldelete"><img src="com/assets/images/remove.png" /></a></th>
            <th colspan="2" style="text-align:left;">C Full <a href="#ratecardinfo" class="coldelete"><img src="com/assets/images/remove.png" /></a></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="labelrow">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="80px"><label>COST</label></td>
            <td width="80px"><label>SALE</label></td>
            <td width="80px"><label>COST</label></td>
            <td width="80px"><label>SALE</label></td>
            <td width="80px"><label>COST</label></td>
            <td width="80px"><label>SALE</label></td>
            <td width="80px"><label>COST</label></td>
            <td width="80px"><label>SALE</label></td>
            <td width="80px"><label>COST</label></td>
            <td width="80px"><label>SALE</label></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ratedatarow" id="rate15">
            <td>6:30 PM</td>
            <input type="hidden" value="15" name="showtimeids[]" /><input type="hidden" value="101" name="categoryids[]" />
            <td width="50px"><input type="text" value="650.00" name="fc:15:101" style="width:45px;" /></td>
            <td width="50px"><input type="text" value="670.00" id="fs_15_101" name="fs:15:101" style="width:45px;" /></td>
            <td width="50px"><input type="text" value="500.00" name="hc:15:101" style="width:45px;" /></td>
            <td width="50px"><input type="text" value="520.00" name="hs:15:101" id="hs_15_101" style="width:45px;" /></td>
            <input type="hidden" value="102" name="categoryids[]" />
            <td width="50px"><input type="text" value="400.00" name="fc:15:102" style="width:45px;" /></td>
            <td width="50px"><input type="text" value="420.00" id="fs_15_102" name="fs:15:102" style="width:45px;" /></td>
            <td width="50px"><input type="text" value="300.00" name="hc:15:102" style="width:45px;" /></td>
            <td width="50px"><input type="text" value="320.00" name="hs:15:102" id="hs_15_102" style="width:45px;" /></td>
            <input type="hidden" value="103" name="categoryids[]" />
            <td width="50px"><input type="text" value="1200.00" name="fc:15:103" style="width:45px;" /></td>
            <td width="50px"><input type="text" value="1240.00" name="fs:15:103" id="fs_15_103" style="width:45px;" /></td>
            <td><a onclick="removeRow('rate15');" href="#ratecardinfo" id="rem"><img src="com/assets/images/remove.png" /></a> <a id="mo_applytoall" onclick="applyToAll('rate15');" href="#ratecardinfo"> Apply to All </a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#DDDDDD;" colspan="11"></td>
            <td style="background-color:#DDDDDD;">
                <input type="submit" style="cursor:pointer;" value="Add Card" name="addratecard" />                    
                <input type="button" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="resetAll();" value="Reset" />                      
                <input type="button" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="clearAll();" value="Clear All" /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I clicked the remove.png, the particular row should be removed.

Thanks

Comment: you are misusing the label tag.

Comment: i'm sorry i dont get what you say

Comment: the `label` tag is used to mark a label for a form element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery remove HTML table column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068881/jquery-remove-html-table-column)

Comment: please refer the code i have mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work..

```
$("a").on("click", function(){
    $("table tbody tr").find("td:eq(0)").remove(); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/peterbenoit/ymYpv/

Answer (score 1):

the most efficient way would be to give all the cells of a column a class, and then you can use the class name to remove the columns.

```
$('.myColumn').remove();
```

Alternatively, you can cycle though the rows, removing each Nth child as required.

```
$('tr').each(function(){
  $(this).children().eg(N).remove();
})
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm unable to add classes to the HTML part. That's why I used above JQuery code.

Comment: did you change the value N for the number of the column you want to remove?

Comment: jQuery("tr.ratedatarow").each(function(){
                          jQuery(this).children().eg(CostIndex).remove();
                          jQuery(this).children().eg(SaleIndex).remove();
                    });

Comment: yeah thanks. If you see the code what I have used at the 1st place is the code which you just asked me refer :-(

Comment: is the event firing? put an alert at the start to make sure

Comment: yeah it deletes columns 1 and 3. but what I want to delete is 1 and 2.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UbCFp/4/ Seems to work okay, are you trying to delete single cells from one row?

Comment: it does not delete the rates. what I want to delete is the whole 1st and 2nd coloumn

Answer (score 1):

in function `removeRow` try

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Comment: removeROW function works. What I want to do is to remove the columns

Comment: which columns do you want to remove ?

Comment: depending on the img the user click. if we click the 1st remove.png, column 1 and 2 should be removed

Comment: so you want the column and the column to the right of the click to be removed?

Comment: @MildFuzz according to him th has colspan=2 so if user clicks delete cost and sale both columns should be removed.